# Do I need to create index for PK in SQLite tables?

Tags: sqlite

If I have a single column integer PK on a SQLite table - do I need to create explicit index or is it take care of by the engine?

Same question for **string/text** single field PK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [UNIQUE constraints](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#unique_constraints):

> In most cases, UNIQUE and PRIMARY KEY constraints are implemented by
> creating a unique index in the database. (The exceptions are INTEGER
> PRIMARY KEY and PRIMARY KEYs on WITHOUT ROWID tables.)

If a column is defined as `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` it is actually an alias of the [rowid](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowids_and_the_integer_primary_key) of the column:

> The data for rowid tables is stored as a B-Tree structure containing
> one entry for each table row, using the rowid value as the key. This
> means that retrieving or sorting records by rowid is fast. **Searching
> for a record with a specific rowid, or for all records with rowids
> within a specified range is around twice as fast as a similar search
> made by specifying any other PRIMARY KEY or indexed value**.
> The **exception** mentioned above is that if the declaration of a column with
> declared type "INTEGER" includes an "PRIMARY KEY DESC" clause, it does
> not become an alias for the rowid and is not classified as an integer
> primary key.